# Is there a vs code extension with incorrect steps highlight and "go to step definition" for badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor and typescript?

Tags: typescript, cucumber, gherkin, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

There are many many vs code extensions for visual studio code if I type "cucumber" or "ghekrin" or something similar in search. But they just provide a general syntax highlight and step generation.
The only one that provides incorrect step definitions highlight and "go to definition" functionality is "Cucumber" library, which works only for C# and specflow.
Is there a similar extension for typescript and badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor library?